# Linear transformation of a matrix by given bases

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I am trying to find out the matrix for the following linear transformation with respect to the given bases:
$$
T:\mathbb{R}[x]_{\le 2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[x]_{\le 3} \space \text{given by}\space  T(f)=xf \space \text{in the bases}\space  {1,x,x^2} \space \text{for} \space \mathbb{R}[x]_{\le 2} \space \text{and} \space {1,x,x^2,x^3} \space \text{for} \space \mathbb{R}[x]_{\le 3}
$$

I know that the matrix should have $3$ columns and $4$ rows.

Here is an example of a similar question that I got given in a multiple-choice quiz:

The matrix for the linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}[x]_{\le3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $T(f)=f(3)$ in the basis {${1,x,x^2,x^3}$} for $\mathbb{R}[x]_{\le3}$ and the basis {${1}$} for $\mathbb{R}$ is $(1,3,9,27)$.

This one I found to be pretty straightforward as it's $4$ columns and $1$ row, so you just substitute $3$ in and you get the answer $(1,3,9,27)$.

How can apply what I know from this question to the one that I'm trying to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first element of $\{1,x,x^2\}$ is $1$, and $T(1)=x$, which is the second element of $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$. Also, the second element of $\{1,x,x^2\}$ is $x$, and $T(x)=x^2$, which is the third element of $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$. Finally, the third element of $\{1,x,x^2\}$ is $x^2$, and $T(x^2)=x^3$, which is the fourth element of $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$. So, the matrix that you are after is$$\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$